# How to connect 3 monitors to 2011 Mac Mini

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, thunderbolt

I recently purchased a 2011 Mac Mini and I would like to connect 3 older monitors to it.  Is it possible to do so and keep a separate desktop on each device?  Some background information:

- 1 of my monitors only has a VGA inputs
- 1 of my monitors has VGA AND DVI input
- 1 of my monitors is actually a small flat screen tv and has HDMI and
  VGA inputs
- Mac mini has HDMI port, thunderbolt port, 4 USB ports
- I already have a HDMI to VGA cable

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could investigate Matrox and their [TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/displayport/) product.  I used the DualHead2Go product and it worked very well.  You need to determine whether your specific model, can support the maximum resolution you want.  Note that the Matrox product has DisplayPort outputs, so you'd need to buy adapters for your DVI or VGA displays.

Comment: This is quite an expensive investment just to add another monitor.  Any experience with USB to VGA solutions or anything of that nature?

Comment: Yes, it is, but the task you're trying to accomplish is not easy and you didn't indicate cost as part of your criteria.  I provided you an option, simple as that.